# spamassasin HTML_IMAGE_ONLY

Tags: phpmailer, php, spamassassin

My mails get 1.6 points (out of max 2 to be classified by spam) from this rule:

SpamAssassin Rule: HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_24

Standard description: HTML: images with 2000-2400 bytes of words

Explanation

This may indicate a message using an image instead of words in order to sidestep text-based filtering.

I have two images embedded in my mail - is that really not possible? How am I even to understand the phrase "with 2000 bytes of words".

Shouldnt it less strict if you embedd the images - as the mails grows larger in size and make it less likely to be spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look [here](http://help.campaignmonitor.com/topic.aspx?t=104). If you embed images on your mail you'll reduce HTML code and you should get a smaller score

Comment: Nice article, but either I misunderstand or it doesnt answer my question quite. I already embed the images.

Comment: And it ain't changed your score?

Comment: No this flag is after images are embedded. I thought it was a quality that they were embedded, cause bigger emails should mean less chance of spam.

Comment: Not every time, some spamers add image description in text and it increase the size of the message